# Signal-slot doesn't work using QThread

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qthread

I am using QT framework. I have been using SIGNAL-SLOT for a while. I like it. :-)
But I cannot make it work when I use QThread. I always create new thread using “moveToThread(QThread …)” function.
Any suggestion? :-)

The error message is:

Object::connect: No such slot connection::acceptNewConnection(QString,int) in ..\MultiMITU600\mainwindow.cpp:14
Object::connect: (sender name: 'MainWindow')

I have read about similar problems but those were not connected to QThread.

Thanks, David

EDITED: you asked for source code
Here is one:

Here is the code:

The main class which contains the signal and the new thread:

mainwindow header:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

    …
    QThread cThread;              
    MyClass Connect;
    ...
    signals:

            void NewConnection(QString port,int current);
     …
};
```

The constructor of the above class: .cpp

```
{
    …
        Connect.moveToThread(&cThread1);
           cThread.start(); // start new thread
   ….
connect(this,SIGNAL(NewConnection(QString,int)),
            &Connect,SLOT(acceptNewConnection(QString,int))); //start measuring
…
}
```

The class that contains the new thread and SLOT
Header:

```
class MyClass: public QObject
{
           Q_OBJECT
….
   public slots:
            void acceptNewConnection(QString port, int current);
}
```

And the .cpp file of the above class:

```
void MyClass::acceptNewConnection(QString port, int current){
    qDebug() << "This part is not be reached";

 }
```

Finally I use emit in the class where the connection was made:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    …
emit NewConnection(port, 1); 
}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to actually show the code

Comment: "I always create new thread using “moveToThread(QThread …)” function" does not make any sense, that is not how threads are created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void acceptConnection(QString port, int current) {
        qDebug() << "received data for port " << port;
    }    
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent) {
        myClass.moveToThread(&thread);
        thread.start();
        connect(this, SIGNAL(newConnection(QString,int)), &myClass, SLOT(acceptConnection(QString,int)));
        emit newConnection("test", 1234);
    }

signals:
    void newConnection(QString, int);

private:
    QThread thread;
    MyClass myClass;
};
```

output:
`received data for port  "test"`

Is your `void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()` slot connected to a signal?

Also, for the sake of the clarity and readability of your code, keep the established naming convention and use lower case for object instances and member objects and methods.

Comment: My thread works well. 
After „->start()”; doWork works perfectly. 
I only cannot make SIGNAL-SLOT connection.

I mean other signal-slot.

Comment: I added line to your example to show my problem.
I mean I wanted to write down here. But it is too long, it cannot be written here. How can I add longer comment?

Comment: I don't know why you don't get a connection, check my answer again, I modified the example code with identical to yours and it works.

Comment: @DávidFekete - try to present better looking code with your next question. The way you put this one is pretty chaotic. I prefer to use header-only implementations with inline method definition - it is much more clear and neat to the eye, you can always move your implementations to the CPP later.